# Change Html block with Jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to replace the content of one div whit the content of another.

i have something like this `<div><span>texta</span></div>` and i need to replace with the content of another div in the page.

How do i replace the content of a div with jquery?

Comment: Do you have an id of the divs or at least a class? It would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you have div like this...

```
<div align="center" id="divId">
</div>
```

to change content ..

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    // get the contents of the link that was clicked
    var linkText = $(this).text();

    // replace the contents of the div with the link text
    $('#divId').html(linkText);

    // cancel the default action of the link by returning false
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a cool website, named jQuery.com with a feature called **Documentation** where you can read a lot of cool stuff on manipulating your "HTML":

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

edit:
to make this a little less troll-like, try the following:

```
var stuff = $('<your-element>').clone();
            $('<the-other-element>').html(stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">
        <span>content 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <span>content 2</span>
    </div>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#div1 span").html( $("#div2 span").html() );
});
</script>
```

see it work here:  http://jsfiddle.net/harpax/P7EZw/